# How to run a command after an already running, existing one finishes?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

If I start a script that is going to take a long time, I inevitably realize it after I've started the script, and wish I had a way of doing some kind of alert once it finishes.

So, for example, if I run:

```
really_long_script.sh
```

and press enter...how can I run another command once it finishes?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can separate multiple commands by `;`, so they are executed sequentially, for example:

```
really_long_script.sh ; echo Finished
```

If you wish to execute next program only if the script finished with return-code 0 (which usually means it has executed correctly), then:

```
really_long_script.sh && echo OK
```

If you want the opposite (i.e. continue only if current command has failed), than:

```
really_long_script.sh || echo FAILED
```

You could run your script in a background (but beware, scripts output (`stdout` and `stderr`) would continue to go to your terminal unless you redirect it somewhere), and then `wait` for it:

```
really_long_script.sh &
dosomethingelse
wait; echo Finished
```

If you have already run script, you could suspend it with `Ctrl-Z`, and then execute something like:

```
fg ; echo Finished
```

Where `fg` brings the suspended process to foreground (`bg` would make it run in background, pretty much like started with `&`)

Comment: @mlissner Expanded my answer to cover this case

Comment: Since `fg` returns the value of the job it resumes, you can use `fg && echo Finished` if you want to ensure the command succeeds before executing the other command.

Comment: Ctrl+Z stops a process (for me at least?). `fg` seems to start the same command again. In the case of `youtube-dl` or some other extremely well written programs, that might work, but not for most.

Comment: @FabianRöling Ctrl-Z pauses a process (by sending SIGHUP), and `bg` or `fg` later resumes it (not starts it again). You can try launching some GUI application from a terminal, then press Ctrl-Z in terminal (the app will freeze), then do `fg` (the app will become responsive again). I never encountered any issues despite extensively using Ctrl-Z for many years for a variety of programs. It messes up some fancy screen output (e.g., progressbar), but that is to be expected since you temporary take control of the terminal.

Comment: @aland It literally says "stopped" in the console. And it also doesn't complain when I close the console.

Comment: @FabianRöling Yes, it says "stopped". But you can call `jobs` in the same console to see that the process is still there (albeit, indeed, in a paused/stopped state). You can also call `ps a` and see that the process still exists. It's stopped, but not terminated, and can be resumed (by `fg` or `bg`). If you try to close the console by typing `exit` (instead of closing the terminal window) it _will_ complain about the stopped process.

Comment: Is it safe when I already run multithreading program?

Answer (score 42):

If the process does not run on current tty, then try this:

```
watch -g ps -opid -p <pid>; mycommand
```

Comment: I love the creative use of `watch`. Super  short answer and one learns a new useful way of using watch

Answer (score 20):

You can also use bash's job control. If you started

```
$ really_long_script.sh
```

then press ctrl+z to suspend it:

```
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 really_long_script.sh
$ bg
```

to restart the job in the background (just as if started it with `really_long_script.sh &`). Then you can wait for this background job with

```
$ wait N && echo "Successfully completed"
```

where N is the job ID (probably 1 if you didn't run any other background jobs) which is also displayed as `[1]` above.

Comment: Ensure you prepend N with # like in `wait #1` (otherwise waiting on process id 1)

Answer (score 4):

Turns out this isn't that hard: You can simply type the next command into the window while the existing one runs, press enter, and when the first one finishes, the second command will automatically run.

I'm guessing there are more elegant ways, but this does seem to work.

Editing to add that if you want to run an alert after the command finishes, you can create these aliases in .bashrc, then run `alert` while it is running:

```
 alias alert_helper='history|tail -n1|sed -e "s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//" -e "s/;\s*alert$//"'
 alias alert='notify-send -i gnome-terminal "Finished Terminal Job" "[$?] $(alert_helper)"'
```

Comment: Unless the running script expects input at one point.

Comment: @Daniel - yeah...that's a problem. Shoot.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I have written a script to wait for the end of another process. `NOISE_CMD` could be something like `notify-send ...`, given that `DISPLAY` is set correctly.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

NOISE_CMD="/usr/bin/mplayer -really-quiet $HOME/sfx/alarm-clock.mp3"

function usage() {
    echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") [ PROCESS_NAME [ PGREP_ARGS... ] ]"
    echo "Helpful arguments to pgrep are: -f -n -o -x"
}

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ] ; then
    PATTERN="$1"
    shift
    PIDS="$(pgrep "$PATTERN" "$@")"

    if [ -z "$PIDS" ] ; then
        echo "No process matching pattern \"$PATTERN\" found."
        exit
    fi

    echo "Waiting for:"
    pgrep -l "$PATTERN" "$@"

    for PID in $PIDS ; do
        while [ -d "/proc/$PID" ] ; do
            sleep 1
        done
    done
fi

exec $NOISE_CMD
```

Without any argment, just make some noise immediately. This behavoir allows something like this for convenience (say you call script below `alarm.sh`):

```
apt-get upgrade ; ~/bin/alarm.sh
```

Of course you can do many funny things with such a script, like letting an instance of `alarm.sh` wait for an instance of `alarm.sh`, that is waiting for some other command. Or executing a command just right after some task of a other logged in user has finished... >:D

A former version of the script above might be interesting, if you want to avoid a dependency on `pgrep` and accept to lookup process IDs yourself:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -lt 2 -o ! -d "/proc/$1" ] ; then
  echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") PID COMMAND [ ARGUMENTS... ]"
  exit
fi

while [ -d "/proc/$1" ] ; do
  sleep 1
done

shift
exec "$@"
```

Slightly off-topic, but useful in similar situations: One might be interested in [`reptyr`](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr), a tool that "steals" a process from some (parent) shell and runs it in from current shell. I have tried similar implementations and `reptyr` is the prettiest and most reliable for my purposes.